# Time complexity problem between two different machines

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I've stuck in a problem below.

A particular algorithm has time complexity T(n) = 3T(n-1) + 1.

So, in asymptotic terms, the above algorithm has time complexity of O(3^n).

That exeucting an implementation of the algorithm on a particular machine X takes t seconds for n inputs.

The question is that, Assume that there is a machine Y which is 27times faster than machine X, how many inputs could Y can process in same t second..?

I can solve this problem in my head ambiguously.. but cannot explain anymore.

Is there a simple way of solving this issue?

Comment: What do you think the solution is?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I thought that 27n is an answer, because no matter what algorithm is, Y is 27faster than X. but in other think of way.. n+3 will be the answer.. so I can not grasp the idea

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**: the fast machine will process *n+3* items.

Since the time complexity is *O(3<sup>n</sup>)*. It means that if we increment *n* with one, it will take, approximately three times more time. If we increment *n* with two, then it will thus take nine times more time, and we add three to *n*, then the amount of work will be 27 times more.

So the machine that is 27 times faster, will manage to process three items more than the slow machine. This of course only holds under *asymptotic* conditions: so if *n* is already large. For small *n* the other terms in the equation can have more impact.

More rigorously we can see it as follows: the faster machine can do 27 times the amount of work of the slower machne in the same time.

So that means that:

*T(f(n)) = 27 × T(n)*

Where *f(n)* is the function we want to find. Asymptotically *T(n)* scales with *O(3<sup>n</sup>)*, so that means that we have as equation:

*3<sup>f(n)</sup> = 27 × 3<sup>n</sup>*

and thus holds:

*f(n) =* log<sub>3</sub>*(27×3<sup>n</sup>)*

and therefore:

*f(n) = n+* log<sub>3</sub>*(27)*

Since *log<sub>3</sub>(27)* is equal to *3*, that thus means that:

*f(n) = n+3*

Comment: Thank you so much. I've repeatedly read your explanation. One thing I cannot understand is that, T(f(n)) = 27 × T(n). I understand T(n) as the time consumed dealing with n inputs, since it is time complexity. am I right?

Comment: @jwkoo: T(n) is the number of steps that the machine does. The T(n) at the right is thus the amount of steps the slow machine did to process n elements. We know that in the same amount of time, the fast machine can do 27*T(n), so we are looking what f(n) will satisfy that.

Comment: wow... you are the best. I thought that time complexity for the time consumed for n inputs. Perhaps I have to study the concepts from scratch.